# How to find the eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been given a matrix 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
I expanded by row one twice to get the characteristic polynomial:

$(1-\lambda)^2[(1-\lambda)^2 -1] - 1[(1-\lambda)^2 - 1]$
Which I solved lambda and got that $\lambda = 0$. I checked my work with the answer in the back and its wrong. They got another value for lambda which I can't seem to get.

http://i1317.photobucket.com/albums/t638/ayoshnav/Snapshot_20140326_zps80f4ba36.jpg
http://i1317.photobucket.com/albums/t638/ayoshnav/Snapshot_20140326_1_zpsf7f28df4.jpg

Comment: As the characteristic polynomial has degree 4, it has 4 roots (counting multiplicity). Zero is certainly an eigenvalue, but the eigenvalues add up to the trace, which is 4. It would be easier to read your question if you put some effort into formatting it.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format on this website. Let me take a picture of my work and post the link. Hopefully, that will be easier to understand.

Comment: All you have to do (in this case) is put a dollar sign at each end of the expression, and a backslash in front of each lambda.

Comment: The system matrix can be decomposed into the upper left 2x2-matrix and the lower right 2x2-matrix. These sub-systems do not influence each other. The 2x2-subsysytems are equal. The eigenvalue problem for the 'subsystem-prototype' $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ is very easy to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial you calculated is correct, however, it simplifies to $$p(\lambda) = \lambda^2(\lambda - 2)^2$$

There is more than one solution to the equation $p(\lambda)=0$.

In your notes, the mistake you made was at the very end. You got that $$(1-\lambda)^2 = 1$$ and from that, you concluded that $$(1-\lambda)=1.$$

Why is this wrong? Well, for example, $(-2)^2 = 4 = 2^2$, but that does not mean that $-2=2$, now does it?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to explicitly find eigenvectors - given the form of your matrix, it's quite easy.

First, the vectors $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
are obviously eigenvectors; the corresponding eigenvalue is $2$.

Then again,
the vectors $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$ are eigenvectors, too, with eigenvalue $0$.

We've found $4$ different eigenvectors, the matrix is $4\times 4$, hence we can conclude that we found all eigevalues.

Comment: This is of course true, but in general, finding eigenvectors is at least as hard a problem as finding eigenvalues. A sharp eye can of course help, but not in the general sense.

Comment: @5xum of course, in most cases we need a lot of work. Yet sharp eyes can sometimes save a lot of time and effort=)